# CUDA memory operation order within a single thread

Tags: cuda

From the CUDA Programming Guide (v. 5.5):

> The CUDA programming model assumes a device with a weakly-ordered
> memory model, that is:
>
> - The order in which a CUDA thread writes data to shared memory, global memory, page-locked host memory, or the memory of a peer device
>   is not necessarily the order in which the data is observed being
>   written by another CUDA or host thread;
> - The order in which a CUDA thread reads data from shared memory, global memory, page-locked host memory, or the memory of a peer device
>   is not necessarily the order in which the read instructions appear in
>   the program for instructions that are independent of each other

However, do we have a *guarantee* that the (dependent) memory operations as seen from the single thread are actually consistent? If I do - say:

```
arr[x] = 1;
int z = arr[y];
```

where `x` happens to be equal to `y`, and no other thread is touching the memory, do I have a *guarantee* that `z` is 1? Or do I still need to put some `volatile` or a barrier between those two operations?

---

*In response to Orpedo's answer*.

> If your compiler doesn't compile the functionality stated by your code into equal functionality in machine-code, the compiler is either broken or you haven't taken the optimizations into consideration...

My problem is what optimizations (done either by compiler or hardware) are allowed?
It could happen --- for example --- that `store` instruction is non-blocking and the `load` instruction that follows somehow is managed by the memory controller *faster* than the already queued-up `store`.

I don't know CUDA hardware. Do I have a *guarantee* that the above will never happen?

Comment: The compiler guarantees that dependent operations will not be executed out of order.  I think the reason this is not obvious in the CUDA programming model is that the requirement actually arises out of C/C++ language requirements, which CUDA *mostly* adheres to for code executed in a single thread.  For most architectures, the compiler under the hood is a LLVM toolchain, which implements the C/C++ language requirements, when emitting code.  I'm reasonably sure such a guarantee can be found in C/C++ language requirements, although I don't know how to extract it for you.

Comment: CUDA *mostly* adheres to C++. C++ assumes a completely uniform memory block. CPUs have their caches, but the hardware is built in such a way that caching remains functionally transparent. This is not true on NVIDIA GPU which has an explicit memory hierarchy, exposed to the user through CUDA. While the CUDA compiler is also using LLVM, at the end there is a translation from LLVM bytecode to native assembly, and some additional operations - beyond the scope of LLVM - may happen there; possibly including translation and reordering of memory operations.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: The only problem I see with that line of thinking is that we only have the niceties of C++ formalism at the compiler level. And the compile can't know *a priori* that the code in the question represents aliasation of the same location in memory. So it can't do anything nice to make that particular read after write operation safe (like holding the value in a register and reusing it rather than issuing another memory load).

Comment: You are judging the CUDA programming module, which is apparently current and valid (Otherwise programmer couldn’t work) ; the compiler has to take care of the load store order. The only reason I can see this code may cause some problem is optimization usage of __restrict__ keyword

Answer (score 3):

The CUDA Programming Guide simply stating, that you cannot predict in which order the threads is executed, but every single thread will still run as a sequential thread.
In the example you state, where x and y are the same and NO OTHER THREAD is touching the memory, you DO have a guarantee that z = 1.
Here the point being, that if you have several threads dooing operations on the same data (e.g. an array), you are NOT guaranteed that thread #9 executes before #10.

Take an example:

```
__device__ void sum_all(float *x, float *result, int size N){
  x[threadId.x] = threadId.x;
  result[threadId.x] = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    result[threadId.x] += x[threadID.x];
}
```

Here we have some dumb function, which SHOULD fill a shared array (x) with the numbers from m ... n (read from one number to another number), and then sum up the numbers already put into the array and store the result in another array.
Given that you your lowest indexed thread is enumerated thread #0, you would expect that the first time your code runs this code x should contain

x[] = {0, 0, 0 ... 0} and result[] = {0, 0, 0 ... 0}

next for thread #1

x[] = {0, 1, 0 ... 0} and result[] = {0, 1, 0 ... 0}

next for thread #2

x[] = {0, 1, 2 ... 0} and result[] = {0, 1, 3 ... 0}

and so forth.
But this is NOT guaranteed. You can't know if e.g. thread #3 runs first, hence changing the array x[] before thread #0 runs. You actually don't even know if the arrays are changed by some other thread while you are executing the code.

Comment: If I have a guarantee for what you are saying - where does it say so? I *do* understand the concept of racing between threads. However, for a single thread, with complex (and explicit!) memory model which CUDA exhibits (global, shared, L2&L1 caching...) it is not obvious if all operations are guaranteed to be executed in-order, unless extra measures are applied (e.g. threadfence)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if this is explicitly stated in the CUDA documentation (I wouldn't expect it to be), as this is a basic principle of computing. Basically what you are asking is, if running your code on a GFX will change the functionality of your code.

The cores of a GPU are generally the same, as that of a CPU, just with less control-arithmetics, a smaller instructionset and typically only supporting single-precision.
In a CUDA-GPU there is 1 program counter for each Warp (section of 32 synchronous cores). Like a CPU, the program counter increases by magnitude of one address element after each instruction, unless you have branches or jumps. This gives the sequential flow of the program,  and this can not be changed.
Branches and jumps can only be introduced by the software running on the core, and hence is determined by your compiler. Compiler optimizations can in fact change the functionality of your code, but only in the case where the code is implemented "wrong" with respect to the compiler
So in short - Your code will always be executed in the order it is ordered in the memory, no matter if it is executed on a CPU or a GPU. If your compiler doesn't compile the functionality stated by your code into equal functionality in machine-code, the compiler is either broken or you haven't taken the optimizations into consideration...

Hope this was clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you're basically asking whether memory dependencies and alias analysis information are being respected in the CUDA compiler.

The answer to that question is, assuming that the CUDA compiler is free of bugs, yes because as Robert noted the CUDA compiler uses LLVM under the hood and two basic modules (which, at the moment, I really **don't think they could be excluded by the pipeline**) are:

- [Memory dependence analysis](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#memdep-memory-dependence-analysis)
- [Alias Analysis](http://llvm.org/docs/AliasAnalysis.html)

These two passes detect memory locations potentially pointing to the same address and use live-analysis on variables (even out of the block scope) to avoid dangerous optimizations (e.g. you **can't write** in a live variable before its next read, the data may still be useful).

I don't know the compiler internals but assuming (as any other *reasonably trusted* compiler) that it will do its best to be bug-free, the analysis that take place in there should really not bother you at all and assure you that **at least in theory** what you just presented as an example (i.e. the dependent-load faster than the store) cannot happen.

What guarantee you that? Nothing but the fact that the company is giving a compiler to use, and there are disclaimers in case it doesn't for exceptional cases :)

Also: aside from the compiler topic, the instruction execution is also dependent on the hardware specification. In this case, a SIMT hardware instruction issuing unit
cfr. http://www.csl.cornell.edu/~cbatten/pdfs/kim-simt-vstruct-isca2013.pdf and all the referenced papers for more information

Comment: I don't need a guarantee that the compiler is bug-free. I want a guarantee that the compiler (and hardware!) are *expected* to respect the order of possibly dependent memory operations. In C++ we have standards and if I dig into it I would probably find a section on the order of operations. But there is no CUDA standard, besides the Programming Guide that I know of, and PG does not explicitly specify my case.

Comment: Since it's a proprietary technology, you don't expect to find any public paper covering in great detail all of the CUDA features and expected behavior (thing that would greatly limit programmers' flexibility), are you? Besides what you're asking depends on the hardware too.. and that's proprietary technology also off-limit. You'll have to take their word.

Comment: OK. I will take their word! But what is their word on this subject - I couldn't find any... I was hoping that maybe I missed something, or maybe someone who is working in NVIDIA and is permitted to shed some light on it (happened before on SO)